# How to remove all prints in stored procedures / triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several databases with lots of triggers, stored procedures, etc. that contain `PRINT` statements.

Once the tests are finished, I want to remove all these `PRINT` statements that I used for debug issues.

The problem is that I have to check object by object in all databases to find and delete the line that contains the `PRINT` statement. This is non-viable due to the amount of objects that exist.

So I am looking for a way to achieve this without having to check object by object.

Comment: To do this properly you'll need a _SQL Parser_. That will let you find `print` statements and not get tripped up by string literals and comments containing the word "print", ... .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by joining the system catalog views **[`sys.sql_modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[`sys.objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) [Schema], 
       O.Name ObjectName,
       O.Type ObjectType
FROM sys.sql_modules M
INNER JOIN sys.objects O
ON O.object_id = M.object_id
WHERE M.definition LIKE '%PRINT%'
```

See how it's working on this **[`Live Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43675d11e17a5a05b83abf20890f2960)**

And if you want to return the definition, you can just add `definition` column in your `SELECT` statement as

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) [Schema], 
       O.Name ObjectName,
       O.Type ObjectType,
       M.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules M
INNER JOIN sys.objects O
ON O.object_id = M.object_id
WHERE M.definition LIKE '%PRINT%'
```

Comment: Thx Sami, but this only returns the name. I'm looking for a full text declaration of this object. (create/alter trigger/stored)

Comment: you make my day. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Won't that return any stored procedure that references the table `Sprinters` and a few other false positives?